# Showing that multiplication is stable in finite arithmetic

Tags: numerical-methods

I need to show that multiplication is stable in finite arithmetic if $x$ and $y$ are real and $$\tilde{x}=x\left(1+\epsilon_x\right),\hspace{5mm}\tilde{y}=y\left(1+\epsilon_y\right)$$
are their real approximation on a computer.

If  $|\epsilon_x|,|\epsilon_y|<\epsilon$, I need to show that the relative error is such that 
$$\frac{|\tilde{x}\tilde{y}-xy|}{|xy|}\le2\epsilon+\mathcal{O}\left(\epsilon^2\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{|\tilde{x}\tilde{y}-xy|}{|xy|}&=\frac{|xy\left(1+\epsilon_x\right)\left(1+\epsilon_y\right)-xy|}{|xy|}
\\&=\frac{|xy\left(\left(1+\epsilon_x\right)\left(1+\epsilon_y\right)-1\right)|}{|xy|}
\\&=\frac{|xy||\left(1+\epsilon_x\right)\left(1+\epsilon_y\right)-1|}{|xy|}
\\&=|\left(1+\epsilon_x\right)\left(1+\epsilon_y\right)-1|
\\&=|1+\epsilon_x+\epsilon_y+\epsilon_x\epsilon_y-1|
\\&=|\epsilon_x+\epsilon_y+\epsilon_x\epsilon_y|
\\&\le|\epsilon_x|+|\epsilon_y|+|\epsilon_x\epsilon_y|
\\&\le2\epsilon+\mathcal{O}\left(\epsilon^2\right)
\end{align}$$
as desired